# Too many query rows: 50001 in Production

Tags: trigger, soql, governorlimits, data-loader, limitexception

We are getting Too many query rows: 50001 error in production during a data load activity of an Sobject. we have an active trigger on this Sobject. But we have only 14K records for this object in Production. How come we get 50K rows retrived erorr when we have only 14K records for this object? Does this add the rows retrieved for all SOQL statements executed during the data load? Anyone any idea please?

Comment: See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm) regarding Apex transactions and governor limits.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this add the rows retrieved for all SOQL statements executed during the data load?

Yes. This limit is calculated based on the number of records returned by queries conducted by your transaction. If you have 14k records but get this error, this means that something in your transaction is querying other records, or you have a loop querying the same records multiple times.